# Use for dynamic object property names in angular reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

In code below

```
<div *ngSwitchCase="'arraytext'" >
      <label class="col-sm-6" [formArrayName]="question.key" *ngFor="let order of form.controls.options.controls; let i = index">
      <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i" class="form-control">{{order.value}}
      </label>
</div>
```

Here **options** is checkbox input for dynamic form and for another checkbox input may be **option-2**.

So my question is how to have **form.controls.options.controls** dynamic instead of using hard-coded **options**

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qvqzmr-w49yc9). Here I managed to get the checkbox values, but the problem is how to have more than one checkbox. **form.controls.options.controls** is hard coded

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic? what exactly are you trying to achieve? is form a formGroup? please include your entire form and a bit more relevant code.

Comment: if you make stackblitz that would be the best.

Comment: @Vato i will update soon. But this post is continuation of my previous post https://stackoverflow.com/a/58006093/8632727

Comment: Here i want multiple check boxes dynamically