# Angular - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'angular'

Tags: angular

I am trying to loop trough a list in angular:

```
const myList = [];
angular.forEach(myList, function(value, key {
}
```

I got following error:

> 'angular' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module.
>   Consider adding an import instead.

Which is why I tried to do the import:

```
import * as angular from "angular";
```

But as soon as I tried this, the program failed to compile completely and I got following error:

> ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'angular'  Parsed request is a module

I don't understand this, what am I doing wrong? How can i run a for-each loop trough a list in Angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no forEach in angular, it is available only in angularjs.

In order to iterate over list, you need just use **`forEach`** over the array of items

```
myList.forEach((element) => {
    console.log(element);
});
```

Comment: I then get "Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'void'."

Comment: Problem is in this line const mappedData = this.mapChartData(jsonData.data, "test");. which does not return anything

Comment: @RameshRajendran Perfect, Thanks!

Comment: @Sajeetharan please help me in this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/58010831/8632727

Answer (score 1):

Whatever @Sajeetharan said is correct. To remove this error just replace that line by  `const filesarray = this.readDocument(csvdata) as any;`

[Updated code](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-8fth2)

**But you should return some data from `readDocument()` for proper solution**

Comment: do you know why readDocument() does not return anything? When a folder with csv files is uploaded, readDocument() is supposed to return a list with all the values from the files. I don't know why it doesn't.