# Angular - Getting error as `Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'angular'`

Tags: javascript, angular

When I tried to add custom JS in module.ts using this:

```
var my_app = angular.module("my_app",[]);
```

I get this error:

> Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'angular'

Although I ran the below:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
npm install -save-dev @type/angular
```

Then I imported the same in module.ts:

```
import * as angular from 'angular'
```

It doesn't show any red flags in VS but upon running it I get the above error.

I was just trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_intro.asp)

I checked the the [stack query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58061319/angular-module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-angular), didn't get much help.

Comment: Im very confused about what you are trying to do.
To start an Angular project you install the cli with `npm install -g @angular/cli` and then create a new project with `ng new my-project`

Comment: var my_app = angular.module("my_app",[]); it works with angular 1.* version, all later versons use ng new command to create project.

Comment: Hi @Eknot @Megh, i was just trying to follow this tutorial `https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_intro.asp`

Comment: That tutorial is for the AngularJS version (or Angular 1) which has been deprecated. If you want to learn Angular 2+, you can follow this tutorial https://angular.io/tutorial